# Have you ever seen logarithmic burn-in on a Kalman filter before?

Tags: kalman-filters

I'm reviewing a paper that uses a multiplicative factor $\ln i$ where $i$ is the number of steps since the Kalman filter was initialized.  The idea is to slowly build confidence as the filter sees more data.

The authors replace the typical Kalman gain $K$ with one weighted by this multiplicative factor $K_{new}$:

> $K_{new} = ( \ln i) K$

Have you ever seen such an approach used before? I'd like to give the authors a reference to cite to tie them into the literature on this subject if it exists.

Comment: Can you give some related examples or references? It is not clear in which step of the KF implementation, the authors are using the multiplicative factor.

Comment: @Maxtron I've updated the question to clarify a bit. Please let me know if more clarification is needed.

Comment: I can't really comment anything about the scale factor without having looking at the reference. The original KF implementation does not include scale factors.

Comment: @Maxtron If it doesn't remind you of ANY KF you've seen before, I think that answers my question (at least for one other person).  If you'd like to be a reviewer of the paper, I could ask the editors.

Comment: Perhaps, you can wait for a few more days until someone responds to this question. A samples size of one is too small. You can also ask the author to provide references or derivation of the scale-factored KF.

Comment: @Maxtron I have heard back from the authors.  From their answer, it seems this is a (to them) novel heuristic without justification or derivation.

Comment: It makes no sense to derive something without justification. In adaptive LMS algorithm, $\lambda$ would determine the step size and rate of convergence. Do they consider different values of $\lambda$ and demonstrate improvement in convergence? Also, I don't understand the purpose of convergence in Kalman filters.

Answer (score 1):

The authors cite this work in their response to the review:

> Zhao H, Lu L. Adaptive recursive algorithm with
>   logarithmic transformation for nonlinear system identification in
>   α-stable noise [J]. Digital Signal Processing, 2015:S1051200415002535.

They take their inspiration from equation (14):

> $J_p(n)=\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda^{n-1} \cdot \log^p (1+|e(i)|)$

It is notable that $e(i)$ is (as one might expect) the error in the signal, and not linearly increasing with the number of steps since the filter was initialized.